# Can't change the Home Path with jupyterlab desktop app

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I want to open my .ipynb files with the jupyterlab desktop App, however when I change the configs of the jupyter_lab_config.py file to set the base directory to:
`c.ServerApp.root_dir = 'C:/Users/Username/Desktop/'`,

it opens the app with the good home path, but it says: Directory not found
Directory not found: “” and I can’t open my file directly with the app.

Do you know how I can fix this?